# Is it proper for a former State Senator to use the title "Senator" when acting in a voluntary Community Association capacity in a different State?

Tags: formality

Protocol for use of the title "Senator"

Comment: Why do you think it's improper?

Comment: It's modern courtesy to keep referring to an office holder by that title for the rest of their life. It doesn't matter what activity they're doing.

Comment: Presidents are still  addressed as President even in foreign countries.